# Ansible expect module doesn't respond to password prompt

Tags: expect, ansible, pexpect, ansible-2.x

I am trying to create a password to `openvp`n user using Ansible. I am using the `expect` module, but it does not work.

The next is the task I am trying to execute.

```
- name: Crear contraseña
  expect:
    command: passwd openvpn
    responses:
      Question:
        - (?i)Introduzca la nueva contraseña de UNIX: "a1245"
        - (?i)Introduzca la nueva contraseña de UNIX: "a1245"
```

The error is the next:

```
TASK [instalarVPN : Crear contraseña] ******************************************
fatal: [172.16.8.231]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "passwd openvpn", "delta": "0:00:30.108342", "end": "2016-09-14 10:13:07.370289", "failed": true, "rc": 10, "start": "2016-09-14 10:12:37.261947", "stdout": "Introduzca la nueva contraseña de UNIX: ", "stdout_lines": ["Introduzca la nueva contraseña de UNIX: "]}
```

If I use:

```
- name: Crear contraseña
  expect:
    command: passwd openvpn
    responses:
      (?i)Introduzca la nueva contraseña de UNIX: "a1245"
      (?i)Introduzca la nueva contraseña de UNIX: "a1245"
```

I have the next error:

```
fatal: [172.16.8.231]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_98VaZx/ansible_module_expect.py\", line 230, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_98VaZx/ansible_module_expect.py\", line 151, in main\r\n    events[key.decode()] = response\r\nUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the syntax for multiple prompts and answers:

```
- name: Crear contraseña
  expect:
    command: passwd openvpn
    responses:
      (?i)Enter new password: "a1245"
      (?i)Enter new password: "a1245"
```

Notice: `ñ` is a Unicode character, so it might require quoting, or you can change the language to English.

You need Ansible 2.1 - per `responses` argument description in the [`expect`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) module doc:

> If the response is a list, successive matches return successive responses. List functionality is new in 2.1.

---

That said, it's somewhat cumbersome to use `expect` module to do what you can achieve "natively" with the [`user`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html) module.

Comment: I have edited the question, when I use the task you answered me I have an error, check it in the question please. Yes I have ansible 2.1.0.0

Comment: Okey It works fine, I have change the system language to English, the problem is what you say that the 'ñ' can't decode. Can you edit the answer and I accept it?

Comment: Yes, I tested it in English and put your strings, as I don't speak Spanish. Will update, but the string is different on Linux, different on OS X, so...